# storageclass.storage.k8s.io "gp2" not found even though created the gp2

Tags: kubernetes, storage-class

Now I am install the prometheus in kuberentes cluster like this:

```
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus \
    --namespace reddwarf-monitor \
    --set alertmanager.persistentVolume.storageClass="gp2" \
    --set server.persistentVolume.storageClass="gp2"
```

and I found the PVC was bind to storage class, then I create the storage class like this:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: gp2
  namespace: default
provisioner: fuseim.pri/ifs
```

but the PVC still shows error `storageclass.storage.k8s.io "gp2" not found`. I have already create the nfs deployment client like this:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-client-provisioner
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nfs-client-provisioner
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nfs-client-provisioner
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nfs-client-provisioner
      containers:
        - name: nfs-client-provisioner
          image: quay.io/external_storage/nfs-client-provisioner:latest
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nfs-client-root
              mountPath: /persistentvolumes
          env:
            - name: PROVISIONER_NAME
              value: fuseim.pri/ifs
            - name: NFS_SERVER
              value: 3659b4xxx-pli55.cn-shanghai.nas.aliyuncs.com
            - name: NFS_PATH
              value: /k8s/storageclass
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-client-root
          nfs:
            server: 3659b4ab7c-pli55.cn-shanghai.nas.aliyuncs.com
            path: /data/k8s/storageclass
```

create service account like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: nfs-client-provisioner
  namespace: default

---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-client-provisioner-runner
  namespace: default
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["persistentvolumes"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "delete"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["persistentvolumeclaims"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "update"]
  - apiGroups: ["storage.k8s.io"]
    resources: ["storageclasses"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["events"]
    verbs: ["list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["endpoints"]
    verbs: ["create", "delete", "get", "list", "watch", "patch", "update"]

---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: run-nfs-client-provisioner
  namespace: default
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: nfs-client-provisioner
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nfs-client-provisioner-runner
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Am I missing something? what shoul I do to make the PVC find the storage class? this is the kubernetes version info:

```
> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.0", GitCommit:"ab69524f795c42094a6630298ff53f3c3ebab7f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-07T18:16:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/arm64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"26", GitVersion:"v1.26.7", GitCommit:"84e1fc493a47446df2e155e70fca768d2653a398", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-07-19T12:16:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
WARNING: version difference between client (1.23) and server (1.26) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

should I put the pvc with the same namespace with stroage class? I did not found the namespace with storage class.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the k8s 1.20 remove the support for selfLink. https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-api-machinery/1164-remove-selflink, just replace the image not based on selfLink will fixed this issue, just replace the deployment image to `gcr.io/k8s-staging-sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.0`.